# Reverting back from a Cognos 10 import

Tags: cognos

I have imported a full content store from Cognos 8 into my Cognos 10.1 environment, thinking it would merge the existing data into my Cognos 10 data....needless to say I am now very sad.  Is there a way to revert back to the previous environment with out a backup?

Comment: Always, always make backups.

Comment: Agreed...fortunately, this was a playground. And only a couple of people were actually using the data that was available.

Answer (score 2):

There is no revert or rollback capability built into Cognos, so without a backup of your content store database, you are out of luck.

I would recommend that you perform regular backups of your environments.  You should also implement some type of version control / deployment tool for Cognos (e.g. MotioCI).

MotioCI proactively versions all changes in Cognos, and will assist you with these types of deployments.  It also has "undo" capability for deployments (if you want to roll back an entire deployment, you can do it very easily).

You can find additional information here:

http://www.motio.com/products/ci/cognos-version-control.do

Also - this article will give you some good ideas on what you should be versioning in Cognos:

http://info.motio.com/Blog/bid/76378/4-Common-Version-Control-Scenarios-in-Cognos-Connection